# Linux command "logname" not working in java

Tags: java, linux, terminal, ubuntu-14.04

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I tried to execute the logname command as sudo user from java but it returns null. The code I tried is as follows:

```
try {            
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logname");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String sa = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("Logged User: "+sa);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
```

The output I get is

> Logged User: null

I also tried

> String[] temp = {"/bin/sh","-c","logname"} exec(temp);
>
> String[] temp = {"/bin/sh","-c","sudo logname"} exec(temp);
>
> exec("sudo logname");

Update 1:

I tried whoami|awk '{print $1}' for finding the logname. But that did not work. If I am logged in as root, it shows root.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use the full path to the application you are trying to execute?

```
/usr/bin/logname
```

or

```
/usr/bin/whoami
```

what about using:

```
"echo $SUDO_USER"
```

This appears to work:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class runlogname {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    try 
        {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
        pb.command("/bin/bash", "-c", "/usr/bin/logname").start();
        Process p = pb.start();
        int retValue = p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("retValue = " + Integer.toString(retValue));

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";           
        while ((line = br.readLine())!= null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }

        String sa = output.toString();
        System.out.println("Logged User: "+sa);
        } 
    catch (IOException ex) 
        {
        System.out.println(ex);
        }
    catch (InterruptedException ex)
        {
        System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

but return code 1 is returned by the logname command which indidicates an error according to the man page. So this means that the java code is correct but the logname command does not work.

Running strace (with the -f flag) of the example I provided will give you the reason why it fails.

On my box it was:

```
[pid 29925] write(2, "/usr/bin/logname: ", 18) = 18
[pid 29925] write(2, "no login name", 13) = 13
[pid 29925] write(2, "\n", 1)           = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried /usr/bin/logname but it did not work. Regarding "whoami" and "echo $USER", I have root access through sudo but I want the name of the current logged in user that is my java app will run as root but I need the name of the current logged in user.

Comment: I understand that you want output from certain commands. I noticed that $SUDO_USER is set by sudo and shows the username of the user which executed sudo.

Comment: Any ideas about this?

Comment: I updated my answer.. My guess is that the environment (provided by the java runtime) you execute logname is inadequate.

Comment: Environment? if you are mentioning about jdk, I am using 8.05 in my linux machine. I ran the code. It returned retValue = 1 and Logged User: .I am new to running strace so I don't know about it. How can I do that?

Comment: Perhaps you should read http://jorge.fbarr.net/2014/01/19/introduction-to-strace/ which tells you how to use it with some simple examples.

Comment: My suggestion is that you run the example with strace and write the output to a logfile. Then run logname trough strace and write the output to another logfile. Then you shoule be able to compare the two runs and see what is different when logname is being executed trough your application/the java VM.

Comment: Paste bin link for the two straces: Strace from command line: http://pastebin.com/B4GWfG0D       Strace from java: http://pastebin.com/3mzPw1d6. As I said I am new to straces, please take a look I am also trying to interpret it.

Comment: If you google for "logname no terminal" you will see you are not the only one having this issue.

Comment: Ya, I saw that. What surprises me is that the command works in terminal but not in java.

Comment: I tried `ps-e|grep $LOGNAME`, it returns nothing. `ps-u $LOGNAME` returns a list of process.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing "/bin/sh" with "/bin/bash". If you have Ubuntu you probably have the bash shell, not sh.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Sadly, replacing sh with bash did not work. I want the commands to execute to all *nix based systems not only Ubuntu